# How do you convert TopoJSON linestring to polygon?

Tags: topojson

I have a TopoJSON file containing the boundaries of various districts in Uttar Pradesh, India. When you load the data on a map, you see only the outlines of the districts; the districts themselves are not filled.

I believe the problem is that each district is of type `GeometryCollection` that has its own `geometries` made up of a series of `LineString`s.

Instead, I want each district to be of type `Polygon` that just has `arcs`.

For example, the first object is:

```
    {
        "type": "GeometryCollection",
        "geometries": [{
            "type": "GeometryCollection",
            "properties": {
                "district_number": 1,
                "district_name": "Ghaziabad"
            },
            "geometries": [{
                "type": "LineString",
                "arcs": [0]
            }, {
                "type": "LineString",
                "arcs": [1]
            }, {
                "type": "LineString",
                "arcs": [2]
            }, {
                "type": "LineString",
                "arcs": [3]
            }, {
                "type": "LineString",
                "arcs": [4]
            }, {
                "type": "LineString",
                "arcs": [5]
            }]
    }
```

I think I want to convert it, and every other object, to:

```
    {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "properties": {
            "district_number": 1,
            "district_name": "Ghaziabad"
        },
        "arcs": [[0,1,2,3,4,5]]
    }
```

I could fix it manually, but that seems insane. Is there a better way?

## Update

So I figured out how to convert the object into the result I thought I wanted, but I got some very wacky polygons. Here is my (very clunky) code. Thanks to Saeed Adel Mehraban for some guidance with this.

```js
   d3.json('map.topojson',function(error,data){ // get my json that needs to be converted

    var arr = data.objects.collection.geometries; // this is the relevant array
    var newArr = [];  // in order to map each object, i need to put each one into a new array as a single-item array

    arr.forEach(function(d,i){
      var curr = [d];
      newArr.push(curr);
    })

    newArr.forEach(function(e,i){ // now that i have my new array, i want to convert each object that contains a LineString into a Polygon

      var output = e.map(function(d){

        var arcsArr = []; // an empty array to push each single value of the LineString arcs into
        return {
          "type": "Polygon", // change the type to polygon
          "properties": d.properties, // keep the properties
          "arcs": d.geometries.map(function(g) { // a single key-value pair for arcs, made up of the individual arcs from the LineString
            arcsArr.push(g.arcs[0]);
            return [arcsArr]; // the array of arcs must be in another array
          })
        };

      });

      var output = output[0]; // get only the first item in the output array, which is the object i have modified
      output.arcs = output.arcs[0]; // and change the arcs so we're only taking the first array (as we've duplicated the arrays)
      $('body').append(JSON.stringify(output)+','); // append the whole thing to the body so I can copy it and paste it into the appropriate part of the JSON
    });
  });
```

This "worked" in the sense that my `LineString`s were indeed converted to `Polygon`s, retaining the original border. But the polygons themselves are a nightmare, with straight lines crisscrossing the map at all kinds of angles.

Is there something like a command line tool that can convert boundaries made of `LineString`s into `Polygon`s?

Comment: Likewise, I could convert this in a GeoJSON file format. But I still haven't found a good way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I ran into the same problem being described.

This is Zambia drawn as a svg polyline foreach arc (red being the first arc listed, and magenta being the last):

[image: Zambia drawn as a svg polyline foreach arc]

However when attempting to create a polygon by concatenating the arcs:

[image: concatenated arcs]

What happened was the arcs for **every** object were listed clockwise, but the points in **every** individual arc were listed counterclockwise. Without seeing the topojson that OP is using I cannot 100% confirm this, but I suspect that this was the case.

I solved this by reversing the points in an arc before pushing them to the array of points to draw the polygon and now all is well:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a map function like below? (I write that with simplistic assumption about data schema. I can't guarantee that it works for complex linestrings since I'm not familiar with topojson format. But it works with your provided data)

```js
var foo = [
  {
    "type": "GeometryCollection",
    "geometries": [{
      "type": "GeometryCollection",
      "properties": {
        "district_number": 1,
        "district_name": "Ghaziabad"
      },
      "geometries": [{
        "type": "LineString",
        "arcs": [0]
      }, {
        "type": "LineString",
        "arcs": [1]
      }, {
        "type": "LineString",
        "arcs": [2]
      }, {
        "type": "LineString",
        "arcs": [3]
      }, {
        "type": "LineString",
        "arcs": [4]
      }, {
        "type": "LineString",
        "arcs": [5]
      }]
    }]
  }
];
var bar = foo.map(function(d) {
  return {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "properties": d.geometries[0].properties,
    "arc": d.geometries.map(function(g1) {
      return g1.geometries.map(function(g) {
        return g.arcs[0];
      });
    })
  };
});

console.log(bar);
```